# Need help on a basic python script that moves the robot through joint movements

Tags: ros2, universal-robot, ur10

I'm currently trying to make the UR10 robot move through ROS2 and I need help doing it.
Current setup:

- Ubuntu Linux - Jammy Jellyfish (22.04)
- ROS2 Rolling Ridley
- Universal Robots ROS2 Driver (Installed & working)

What I want to achieve:
A python script that has the six angle values of the robot (entered manually). Those angles get send to the robot and the robot moves to them through a joint movement. Just a very barebones script.

I can't find any documentation or just an example script for this type of stuff. Also I'm not a professional ROS/ Linux user. So please explain like I'm just new.
Do you guys have anything for me?

Thank you for helping me!